# Ramanujan congruences and étale cohomology

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, modular-forms

What is a good reference for the story of congruences such as

$$\displaystyle \tau(n) \equiv \sigma(11)(n) \mod\ 691$$

with a conceptual explanation with connections to étale cohomology, etc?

Comment: Brian Conrad was writing a book on this and it was available on his web site. However, the PDF link there seems not to work any more.  If it has been published that would be a modern source complementing the Swinnerton-Dyer notes.

Comment: @T..: Dear T.., I don't believe that Brian's book has been published (so far).

Answer (score 4):

The paper of Swinnerton-Dyer in Lecture Notes in Math 350, as well as Serre's Bourbaki talk on the same topic.

Answer (score 2):

The paper of Deligne, Formes modulaires et représentations $l$-adiques, available at [numdam](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SB_1968-1969__11__139_0), has these things.