# Ramanujan 691 congruence

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

I know how to prove this congruence in two ways (one using basics of modular forms and the other using Hecke operators) and I will be working on proving other such congruences soon.

The congruence states that for $n\geq 1$:

$\tau(n) \equiv \sigma_{11}(n)$ mod $691$.

My main question is why this congruence is so important? I recognise it as a beautiful thing but the only reason I can come up with for it being interesting is that it links a geometrical function with a number theoretical function.

Are there any other reasons why this is interesting/useful?

Comment: The statement of the congruence or a link to it wouldn't harm anyone...

Comment: Oh, I am sorry about this, fixed.

Comment: Philosophically, you could argue that it's interesting because it shows that a cusp form (a deep sophisticated object) can be congruent mod p to an Eisenstein series (a much more explicit and tractable thing).

Comment: Ah right, so this congruence kind of gives more precision to the fact that Eisenstein series generate the space? It tells us a more specific connection between some cusp forms and Eisenstein series?

Comment: When viewed "locally" some highly nontrivial modular forms may become a little bit more trivial?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Congruences between Hecke eigenforms are outward, "physical" manifestations of corresponding relationships between the associated two-dimensional Galois representations.

In this particular case, Ramanujan's congruence is related to the fact that
$691$ is an *irregular* prime (in the sense of Kummer).  Roughly the idea is that
Eisenstein series relate to reducible two-dimensional Galois representations, and cuspforms to irreducible two-dimensional Galois representations.  The existence of a congruence between the two points to the existence of an object
that is somewhere between reducible and irreducible: a certain reducible two-dimensional Galois representation which is, however, indecomposable.  The existence of this particular reducible, but indecomposable, two-dimensional representation shows that $691$ is an irregular prime.

To see a hint of
how this could be, note that $691$ being an irregular prime means, by class field theory for $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{691})$ --- especially, the theory of the Hilbert Class Field --- that there exists an unramified abelian extension of $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{691})$; so irregularity of $691$ is related to the existence of a certain abelian extension of an abelian extension of $\mathbb Q$, and the
reducible but indecomposable Galois representation will have such a thing as its splitting field.

For more information on this, and related ideas, you might like to read Mazur's article on the subject; see the entry *June 17, 2010: How can we construct abelian extensions* on his [web-page](http://math.harvard.edu/~mazur).

Answer (score 5):

The congruence
$$
\tau(n) \equiv \sigma_{11}(n) \pmod{691}
$$
is one of [several congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_tau_function#Congruences_for_the_tau_function) that have been proven.

Now it is well known that
$$
\Delta(z) = 2 \pi^2  \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \tau(n)q^n.
$$

[Lehmer conjectured](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-14/issue-2/The-vanishing-of-Ramanujans-function-%CF%84n/10.1215/S0012-7094-47-01436-1.short) that $\tau(n) \neq 0$ for all positive integers $n$. As far as I know this has been checked for $n < 10^{11}$. The congruences play a role in showing part of his conjecture.

As to why is it interesting to consider why $\tau(n) \neq 0$ for all positive integers $n$, [see this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31058/the-vanishing-of-ramanujans-function-taun).

Comment: Ah, that makes a bit more sense now. I guess the congruence tells you that $\tau(n)$ is almost always non-zero (I've never viewed it in this way before). It only remains to check $n$ such that $\sigma_{11}(n) \equiv 0$ mod $691$ to prove Lehmer's conjecture. And as your link says, this has powerful meanings in terms of analytic continuations.

Comment: I would recommend you to a paper of Gandhi's about the nonvanishing of $\tau(n)$ if it weren't so full of errors.

Comment: Well to be honest I have only ever seen the importance of the $\Delta$ function in helping to study other spaces of modular forms. The significance of it by itself is not obvious either! I certainly couldn't just dream up such a function and see it as important.

Comment: @fretty Indeed it is very useful to study spaces of modular forms. For instance, the proof that all even weight modular forms of level $1$ is generated by Eisenstein series depends on the $\Delta$ modular form. Also you can show that the even weight modular forms on  $\Gamma_0(N)$ can be generated by [Dedekind $\eta$-functions](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701478v1.pdf) using $\Delta$.

Comment: Yes I know this, but is that basically the reason for inventing this function? Is there any reason why the $\Delta$ function is interesting by itself?

Comment: @fretty In that sense it's like the Dedekind $\eta$-function [see here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96412/applications-and-motivation-of-eta-quotient-generators-and-algorithms). It is a very powerful tool. But certainly we know all about it already (except the nonvanishing of $\tau(n)$ which has already been mentioned.

Comment: Ah, I have recently been reminded that the tau function is important in the theory of partitions too.

Comment: That's because the partition function is related to Dedekind's $\eta$-function, which is related to $\Delta$ which is related to the tau function. So as you can see $\Delta$ is very important.

Comment: With regards to the above comment recall Euler's generating function to see the relation between Dedekind's $\eta$-function and the partition function.

Comment: Yes, I had just forgotten this stuff because I haven't used/read about partitions for a long time.

Comment: @fretty: Dear fretty, $\Delta$ for many reasons, but for the purposes of this question, its importance derives from the fact that it is a Hecke eigenform, indeed, the *first* (in the sense of being of lowest possible weight) such cuspidal eigenform for the full modular group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$.  Regards,

Answer (score 1):

This is an extract to Manin's paper "Periods of parabolic forms and p-adic Hecke Series":

"This congruence is so far, our only clue to understanding the 11-dimensional étale cohomology of the so-called Sato variety"

Even though I don't know what he means, he gives some references to Serre's articles.

Comment: You can also take a look at this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11720/ramanujan-congruences-and-etale-cohomology?rq=1